# Can I Crop GIF like video?

Tags: ios, swift, video, gif

I have Method to Crop video that is..

```
func cropVideo(sourceURL1: NSURL?, statTime:Float, endTime:Float)
    {

        let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        guard let documentDirectory = try? manager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true) else {return}

        guard let url = sourceURL1 else {return}

            let asset = AVAsset(URL: url)
        print(asset)
            let length = Float(asset.duration.value) / 1000
            print("video length: \(length) seconds")

            let start = statTime
            let end = endTime
            var outputURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("output")
            do {
                try manager.createDirectoryAtURL(outputURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                outputURL = outputURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("outPut.mov")
            }catch let error {
                print(error)
            }

            guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else {return}
            exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
            exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4

            let startTime = CMTime(seconds: Double(start ?? 0), preferredTimescale: 1000)
            let endTime = CMTime(seconds: Double(end ?? length), preferredTimescale: 1000)
            let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: startTime, end: endTime)

            exportSession.timeRange = timeRange
            exportSession.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler{
                switch exportSession.status {
                case .Completed:
                    print("exported at \(outputURL)")

                case .Failed:
                    print("failed \(exportSession.error)")

                case .Cancelled:
                    print("cancelled \(exportSession.error)")

                default: break
                }
        }
    }
```

Here, I am getting length = 0.0 also I am getting the file is not supported error. is there any solution? Or any other methods Please let me know... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. Actually I am making that Gif From video.

So I am firstly cropping that video as I want and then I will convert that trimmed video into GIF.

Solved!!!